# How can I redirect the output of unittest? Obvious solution doesn't work

Tags: python, unit-testing, stdout

Here is my code:

```
import unittest
import sys
import os

class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        print "test one"
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_two(self):
        print "test two"
        self.assertTrue(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    sys.stdout = open(dirpath+'/test_logs/demo_test.stdout.log', 'w')
    sys.stderr = open(dirpath+'/test_logs/demo_test.stderr.log', 'w')
    test_program = unittest.main(verbosity=0, exit=False)
```

When I run this, the contents of `demo_test.stdout.log` is only:

```
test one
test two
```

on the screen I still see the output from unittest:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_two (__main__.DemoTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demotest.py", line 12, in test_two
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I want there to be no output on the screen and everything to be logged. (I am running the test as a cron job, so any output to stdout or stderr causes an email to be sent, so I want to be able to specify exactly when this happens, which means I need to be able to control unittest in this regard.)

Comment: Even assigning `sys.__stdout__` and `sys.__stderr__` fails here - I think it's impossible to redirect the output from within python itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

redirect stderr, e.g.:

```
python my_unit_test_launcher.py 2> log.txt
```

Comment: okay, this seems to work.  I'm still not sure why stderr isn't getting redirected anyway, since I explicitly set it to be redirected in my program.

Comment: Because `unittest` runs your test code in a sandbox that wraps std streams.  You are redirecting the output of your test code, but `unittest` doesn't care, because `unittest` normally just captures your output as basically that of a child process then regurgitates it to the context that called it.  The output you are seeing, from `unittest` itself, is completely independent of what you do in the test code.

Comment: output="$(python -u some_tests.py 2>&1)" && echo "$output" # I'm trying this and it still doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 10):

To solve it within your testcode, you could also do the following:

```
import sys
import unittest

class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        print "test one"
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_two(self):
        print "test two"
        self.assertTrue(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo_test = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(DemoTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=sys.stdout).run(demo_test)
```

Comment: `TextTestRunner(stream=sys.stdout)` is just what I was missing. Thanks!